# How to convert list of tuple to dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of tuples of strings: `List[(String, String, String)]`.

How can I convert it into dataframe with Scala?

Comment: Please provide an example of `input` and `output`. Example: `input`: `List("a", "b")` output: `List("ab")`

Answer (score 6):

You create a `SparkSession` (as of Spark 2.0.0) or a `SQLContext`, and then you can use the implicit `toDF()`:

**Spark 1.6 or earlier:**

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test")
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df: DataFrame = list.toDF() // with default column names: _1, _2, _3
val dfWithColNames: DataFrame = list.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

**Spark 2.0.0 or newer**:

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._

val df: DataFrame = list.toDF() // with default column names: _1, _2, _3
val dfWithColNames: DataFrame = list.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `toDF` method:

```
scala> val myList = List(("a1", "a2", "a3"), ("b1", "b2", "b3"), ("c1", "c2", "c3"))
myList: List[(String, String, String)] = List((a1,a2,a3), (b1,b2,b3), (c1,c2,c3))

scala> myList.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3").show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  a1|  a2|  a3|
|  b1|  b2|  b3|
|  c1|  c2|  c3|
+----+----+----+
```

Depending on your config you may need to run `import sqlContext.implicits._`