# Create Dataframe from List of tuples in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to create Dataframe from list of tuples in scala but I am facing issues. I have my list of tuples like:

```
`mylist` = List((17988,2), (17988,54), (17988,41), (17988,1))
```

This is the schema I defined for two columns:

```
 val `outputSchema` =
              StructType(
                List(
                  StructField("SAILORID", StringType, nullable = false),
                  StructField("ACTIVITYID", StringType, nullable = true)))
```

I tried the code below but it is throwing a null pointer exception.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, outputSchema);
```

I tried the one below as well but same null pointer issue:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mylist) 
val df = rdd.toDF("name", "list")
df.show()

mylist = List((17988,2), (17988,54), (17988,41), (17988,1))
```

This is my schema for Dataframe:

```
 val outputSchema =StructType(List(StructField("SAILORID", StringType, nullable = false),StructField("ACTIVITYID", StringType, nullable = true)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, outputSchema);
```

I want result in Dataframe from each tuple in single row in above given list. I should have 4 rows from 4 tuples like:

```
------------------------
| SAILORID | ACTIVITYID |
|----------|------------|
| 17988    |   2        |
| 17988    |   54       |
| 17988    |   41       |
| 17988    |    1       |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, it's hard to follow what happened. Please post the code that gave you the exception and the exception message as well.

Comment: Its a piece of spark streaming job , creating a DF throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? I don't think there is an issue with your code snippet: https://imgur.com/a/cOgrTBY

Comment: Please structure your code to make it understandable. Currently you have lot of duplicate code (e.g. definition of `df`, `outputSchema`, `mylist`) with parts of it out of order and uncompilable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of tuple to dataframe in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228602/how-to-convert-list-of-tuple-to-dataframe-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and got the right output.

with dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
)
```

code:

```
val myList = List((17988, 2), (17988, 54), (17988, 41), (17988,1))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myList)
val df = rdd.toDF("name", "list")
df.show()
```

and result:

```
+-----+----+
| name|list|
+-----+----+
|17988|   2|
|17988|  54|
|17988|  41|
|17988|   1|
+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I copied and pasted your example and it seems like it worked for me.

What version of spark are you using? My versions are:

- Spark: 2.4.1 and
- Scala: 2.11.12

Here is a transcript of my session:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val myList = List((17988,2), (17988,54), (17988,41), (17988,1))
myList: List[(Int, Int)] = List((17988,2), (17988,54), (17988,41), (17988,1))

scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myList)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> val df = rdd.toDF("name","list")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: int, list: int]

scala> df.show
+-----+----+
| name|list|
+-----+----+
|17988|   2|
|17988|  54|
|17988|  41|
|17988|   1|
+-----+----+


scala>
```

Can you try running the statements from my transcript and respond with what you are seeing?

Also, I do not seem to be able to see a createDataFrame with this signature that matches this call:

```scala
spark.createDataFrame(myList, outputSchema)
```

The only method I can see that accepts a list and a schema requires the list to be a java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row].

Here is the list of methods available:

```scala
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame            
def createDataFrame(rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                        
def createDataFrame(rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                                                       
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame   
def createDataFrame(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                                                                
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                                
def createDataFrame(data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                                                                         
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A])(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Comment: @charchit_patidar Did you solve your problem? If so, did my post help you? If so, can you accept it as the answer please? If you are still having the problem, can you add some more information about what is happening now?

Comment: @charchit_patidar if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.